# Why doesn't import work in imported Gradle script?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

Gradle (v2.12 on OSX) can't find the definition of `Grgit` in the following example unless the contents of `git.gradle` were copied into `build.gradle`. How can I fix this error without losing `git.gradle`?

**build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'org.ajoberstar:gradle-git:1.4.2'
  }
}

apply from: 'git.gradle'
```

**git.gradle**

```
import org.ajoberstar.grgit.* 

task clone << {
  Grgit.clone(dir: file('build/repo'), uri: 'git@github.com:user/repo.git')
}
```

---

This is the output:

```
$ gradle clone
...
Execution failed for task ':clone'.
> Could not find property 'Grgit' on task ':clone'.
```

Comment: Maybe you could try saving Grgit to an ext variable in your build.gradle and then use that in your git.gradle? `ext.gg=Grgit` and then in git.gradle, `gg.clone(...`

Comment: @RaGe, thanks! I actually figured that out, and I'm in the process of typing up an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a workaround: Add `Grgit` as an [`ExtraPropertiesExtension`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.ExtraPropertiesExtension.html) `project.ext` to expose it to the imported Gradle script. (Not sure if there's a cleaner way to do this...)

**build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'org.ajoberstar:gradle-git:1.4.2'
  }
}

// expose Grgit to `git.gradle`
project.ext.Grgit = org.ajoberstar.grgit.Grgit

apply from: 'git.gradle'
```

**git.gradle**

```
// no import needed here

task clone << {
  Grgit.clone(dir: file('build/repo'), uri: 'git@github.com:user/repo.git')
}
```

---

**Aside:** By applying `gradle-git`, the plugin automatically
[opens the Git directory of the project's root, and assigns
the result to `project.ext.grgit`](https://github.com/ajoberstar/gradle-git/blob/5ec3b92/src/main/groovy/org/ajoberstar/gradle/git/base/GrgitPlugin.groovy). If you only needed to work with the current project's Git repo, there'd be no need to expose `Grgit` from `build.gradle`, and **git.gradle** could look like this:

```
apply plugin: 'org.ajoberstar.grgit'

task commitReadme << {
  grgit.add(patterns: ['README.md'])
  grgit.commit(message: "Update README for ${rootProject.version}")
}
```